# Android Location Permission error

Tags: android, permissions, location, maps, parse-server

I am attempting to use google Maps API. I have set all the necessary permissions in the manifest file as such:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

When I attempt to use the following code:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

It shows an error that generates by a permission checking code(below). And I do not know what to enter in the block; it seems that the conditional statement is already doing the necessary checks.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
// TODO: Consider calling
// ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
// here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
// public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
// int[] grantResults)
// to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
// for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
return;
}
```

My code :

```
    package com.project.korsa.korsa;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseGeoPoint;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;

import java.util.List;

public class YourLocation extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    LocationManager locationManager;
    String provider;

    TextView infoTextView;
    Button requestKorsaButton;

    Boolean requestActive = false;

    public void requestKorsa(View view) {
        if (requestActive == false) {

            Log.i("MyApp", "Korsa requesed");

            ParseObject request = new ParseObject("Requests");

            request.put("requesterUsername", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());

            ParseACL parseACL = new ParseACL();
            parseACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
            parseACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
            request.setACL(parseACL);


            request.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {

                    if (e == null) {

                        infoTextView.setText("Finding Korsa driver...");
                        requestKorsaButton.setText("Cancel Korsa");
                        requestActive = true;

                    }
                    else infoTextView.setText("Error...");
                }
            });
        } else {

            infoTextView.setText("Korsa Cancelled.");
            requestKorsaButton.setText("Request Korsa");
            requestActive = false;

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Requests");

            query.whereEqualTo("requesterUsername", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());

            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        if (objects.size() > 0) {
                            for (ParseObject object : objects) {

                                object.deleteInBackground();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_your_location);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        infoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoTextView);
        requestKorsaButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.requestKorsa);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location != null) {
            updateLocation(location);
        }
    }

    public void updateLocation(Location location) {

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 10));

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).title("Your Location"));

        if (requestActive == true) {

            final ParseGeoPoint userLocation = new ParseGeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Requests");

            query.whereEqualTo("requesterUsername", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());

            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

                    if (e == null) {

                        if (objects.size() > 0) {

                            for (ParseObject object : objects) {

                                object.put("requesterLocation", userLocation);
                                object.saveInBackground();

                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        /*if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mMap.clear();

        updateLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

Comment: compile time you will get warning if you dont use permission model if target is Marshmallow and above please go through permission model to better understanding https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the code you have to write code for requesting the user to grant permission for

```
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and 
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
```

So the code would be

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
        this,
        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
        PERMISSION_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask for permissions where you are checking for permission. First Check for **permission**

```
 public static boolean checkPermission(final Context context) {
return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
 }
```

Now ask for permissions

```
private void showPermissionDialog() {
if (!LocationController.checkPermission(this)) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
        this,
        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
        PERMISSION_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.floating_button) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Mapview mapview = new Mapview();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mframe_mapview, mapview).addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        alphaAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha_anim);
        launchTwitter(revealView);
    }
}
```

public class Mapview extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private GoogleMap mgoogleMap;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mapview, container, false);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    MapView  mMapView = (MapView)view.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    if(mMapView != null)
    {
        mMapView.onCreate(null);
        mMapView.onResume();
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
    mgoogleMap = googleMap;
    mgoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-34, 151)).title("Marker in Sydney").snippet("i hope to"));
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder().target(new LatLng(-34, 151)).zoom(16).bearing(0).tilt(45).build();
    mgoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}
```

}

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```